# JavaMailSenderImpl ignores plain text version

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I'm using Spring's (4.2.0) JavaMailSenderImpl and the MimeMessageHelper to send a simple HTML mail, for which I create a HTML and a PLAIN TEXT content:

```
String htmlContent = "<html><body>abc</body></html>";
String plainContent = "xyz";
```

I prepare the MimeMessageHelper...

```
final MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper( message, true);
```

...and use it to set the content:

```
helper.setText( plainContent, htmlContent );
```

This seems to work fine, the message ends up with two parts, one plain text, the other html.

But while the resulting mail (after `sender.send( message )` ) consists of two parts, these are not what I expect...

```
--=-K0h7b+9DIT/qrjT258J6
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain

abc

--=-K0h7b+9DIT/qrjT258J6
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
charset=utf-8"></head> <body>abc</body></html>
```

Somehow my plain text content seems to be replaced with a text-only version of the HTML text. So, the simple question is: How can I stop this? I really want to format my plain text and HTML independently from each other... It doesn't seem useful to be able to provide HTML and plain text if one is ignored...

Comment: You'll need to show us what happens in between, and you need to check the message that is being sent, not the one that is being received. The mail client program may be playing games with the contents.

Comment: I have tried two different email clients, so chances are, it's not a client only problem, especially with the given source for the mail. And nothing happens in between, the mail is sent directly after `setText` is called, so everything that happens, happens in the mailer. I have also debugged the message directly when sending and after sending, in both cases in contains my correct plain text, so I have noe clue where it is replaced.

Comment: Could be your SMTP server, then.

Comment: Are you using Exchange?  It often changes the messages to what it believes is best for the client.  It may be rewriting the plain text part with its conversion of the html part.  Since the two parts are really supposed to be the same content, just formatted differently, it probably thinks it's doing you a favor.

Comment: Will have a talk with the mail admin, thanks guys.